# Writing scraped headers from webpages to pandas frame

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Wrote this code to download h1,h2 and h3 headers and write to a pandas frame along with a list of urls but it gives error as unpacking error expected 3 values.

```
def url_corrector(url):
    if not str(url).startswith('http'):
        return "https://"+str(url)
    else:
        return str(url)

def header_agg(url):
    h1_list = []
    h2_list = []
    h3_list = []
    p = requests.get(url_corrector(url),proxies = proxy_data,verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p.text,'lxml')
    for tag in soup.find_all('h1'):
        h1_list.append(tag.text)

    for tag in soup.find_all('h2'):
        h2_list.append(tag.text)

    for tag in soup.find_all('h3'):
        h3_list.append(tag.text)
    return h1_list, h2_list, h3_list

headers_frame = url_list.copy()
headers_frame['H1'],headers_frame['H2'],headers_frame['H3'] = headers_frame.url.map(lambda x: header_agg(x))
```

Any help on how to do it?
Getting this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this to work around this issue. However, still unsure why the original isn't working.

```
headers_frame = url_list.copy()
H1=[]
H2=[]
H3=[]
for url in headers_frame.url:
    k = header_agg(url)
    H1.append(k[0])
    H2.append(k[1])
    H3.append(k[2])
pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([headers_frame.url,H1,H2,H3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that url_list is a dict with the following structure:

```
url_list = {'url': [<url1>, <url2>, <url3>, <url4>, ..., <urln>]}
```

the call to `headers_frame.url.map(lambda x: header_agg(x))` will return a list with n elements in the form:

```
[<url1(h1_list, h2_list, h3_list)>, <url2(h1_list, h2_list, h3_list)>, ..., <urln(h1_list, h2_list, h3_list)>]
```

For the code to produce the output you require, you may have to re-write the last statement as a loop

```
headers_frame.update({'H1':[], 'H2':[], 'H3':[]})
for url in headers_frame.url:
   headers = header_agg(url)
   headers_frame['H1'].extend(headers[0])
   headers_frame['H2'].extend(headers[1])
   headers_frame['H3'].extend(headers[2])
```

Comment: Did something similiar. This is close to the solution which I used. Posted the solution for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return one entity. Just change:

```
return [h1_list, h2_list, h3_list]
```